# How can I make jasmine.js stop after a test failure?

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine

I want the runner to stop after the first failure rather than running all the tests.

Comment: What makes this "not a real question"?

Comment: There's an open issue for this here https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/414. The author has written a plugin https://github.com/goodeggs/jasmine-bail-fast. Unforuntately `this.results()` does not exist for me in my AngularJS unit tests (run by karma).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a hack, but you can do this by inserting this script before your first test;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// after every test has run
afterEach(function () {
  // check if any have failed
  if(this.results_.failedCount > 0) {
    // if so, change the function which should move to the next test
    jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_ = function () {
      // to instead skip to the end
      this.onComplete();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Jasmine's latest commit at the time of applying this was https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/commit/8b02bf731b193e135ccb486e99b3ecd7165bf95c

Comment: `console.log(this.results_)` prints "undefined"

Comment: Yeah, Jasmine v2 has come out since this was posted in 2013

Answer (score 0):

This is a very popular feature request for the jasmine project:
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/414

It looks like there is interest in implementing it, but it has also been open for a very long time, so who knows when it might be released. Alternatively, Mocha implements this feature with its -b/--bail option: https://mochajs.org/#usage. Its api is very similar to Jasmine's so you may want to consider making the switch.