# how to skip to next describe() upon error in previous describe? jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

i'm using such code in order to stop the entire `describe` upon an error in one of the `it()` functions:

```
if(this.results_.failedCount > 0) {
        //next step will finish the test
   jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_ = function () {
   // to instead skip to the end
        this.onComplete();
   }
}
```

i got it from: [How can I make jasmine.js stop after a test failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679951/how-can-i-make-jasmine-js-stop-after-a-test-failure)

however, if i have few describe blocks in the file, and the first describe fails, i would like it to continue to the next describe and not kill the entire test.
how can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asher, 
I've used your code from the workaround inside afterEach and it seems to work. Thanks :)
In case you want the other specs to fail (and not just skipped)
add the following code inside the if:

```
if (currentIt && (currentIt.results_.failedCount !== 0)) {

    var currentSuite = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.suite.id;
    var currentSpec = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.id;

    //get number of children (its)
    var numChildren = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.suite.children().length;

    //skip after last child
    jasmine.getEnv().currentRunner().suites()[currentSuite].queue.index = numChildren-1;
    //finish the current spec now (otherwise the spec will be reported after his siblings)
    jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.finish();
    jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.finishCallback = function(){};

    //report the other sibilings as failures
    for (var index = currentSpec+1; index < numChildren ; index++){
       var spec = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.suite.children()[index];
       jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec = spec;
       (new AddIndexPlugin()).doBefore();

       spec.results().failedCount = 1;
       spec.results().totalCount = 1;
       spec.results().skipped = true;
       spec.results().getItems().push(new jasmine.ExpectationResult({actual:'skipping test because previous test failed',passed:false , message:'skipping test because previous test failed',trace:'skipping test because previous test failed'}));

       spec.finish();
}
```

Now Jasmine is really a E2E testing framework and not just unit test framework.

Comment: Jasmine 2 removed `currentSpec` though.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a simple workaround.

```
if(this.results_.failedCount > 0) {
        //get suite id:
        var currentSuite = jasmine.currentEnv_.currentSpec.suite.id;

        //get number of children (its)
        var numChildren = jasmine.currentEnv_.currentSpec.suite.children_.length;

        //skip to last child
        jasmine.currentEnv_.currentRunner_.suites_[currentSuite].queue.index = numChildren - 1;
}
```

if the test fails, i get the suite id, finds how many children it has (how many `it`s) and then change the index in the runner's queue. it basically skips the rest of the `it`s in the current describe and moves on to the next describe block.