# Printing angular $log statements in Jasmine UTs?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to UT my AngularJS app. It seems to be good practice to use Angular's $log.debug() instead of console.print(), since it can be compiled out.

However, $log messages aren't displayed in my Jasmine UTs, which makes debugging failures difficult.

Is it possible to configure Angular/Jasmine so that the $log messages are collected by the UT runner? Bonus points for function analogous to Python nose's --log-capture, where logs are captured for all tests, but only displayed for failing ones.

Comment: `$log` is recommended because it can be injected in to your service/controller/factory/directcive. That being said, you can mock it out to be and do whatever you want it to do. Whether that be log to console, or to gather an array of messages to do with what you please upon a failed test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually isn't hard at all. The gist is that you need to pull `$log` into your test suite and inject it in your `beforeEach()` block. Then, you can simply dump messages to `console.log` in your `afterEach()` (as below,) or even in your test if you prefer.

```
describe("MyService", function() {
    var MyService, $log;

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function (_MyService_, _$log_) {
            MyService = _MyService_;
            $log = _$log_;
        });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        console.log($log.debug.logs); //do it here to output for every test...
    });

    it("should output debug logs", function() {
        //do something with MyService that would put a message in $log
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        console.log($log.debug.logs); //or here to output for just this test!
    });
});
```

For a deeper explanation and examples of writing out other log levels, I'd suggest reading this article (it's where I learned it):

http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-access-angular-log-debug-messages-from-within-karma/

---

As to your "bonus points" - I don't know anything about Python, but maybe I can point you in the right direction. If you're running Jasmine 1.x, then I think you can inspect the results of the current test like so: `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec`. [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858717/how-to-skip-to-next-describe-upon-error-in-previous-describe-jasmine-test)

However, if you're running Jasmine 2.x, then you're facing the same problem as me, as they've hidden that object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390105/execute-code-after-jasmine-test-failure)'s a question where I've asked for exactly that.

UPDATE: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39882823/3123195) recently provided to my above question uses Jasmine's reporter functionality to polyfill `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec`, so you could indeed use that to only print log statements for failing tests.