# Execute code after Jasmine test failure

Tags: logging, jasmine

Is it possible to do something only if a Jasmine test fails? Juxtaposed with `afterEach()` which executes after an `it()` regardless of outcome, I'm looking for some way to execute code only after an `it()` has a failed expectation.

This question is not Angular-specific, but in my scenario I am testing an Angular service which outputs debug messages using `$log`. I don't want to clutter my console for tests that are successful, but only show the additional information for failing tests.

```
describe("MyService", function() {
    var MyService, $log;

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function (_MyService_, _$log_) {
            MyService = _MyService_;
            $log = _$log_;
        });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        if (/* test failed */) {
            //console.log($log.debug.logs);
        }
    });

    it("should output debug logs when this fails", function() {
        //do something with MyService that would put a message in $log
        expect(false).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

I'm running Jasmine 2.2.0.

Edit: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/Lfvhjdjh/)'s a very simple fiddle which shows the Jasmine 1.3 `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec` solution no longer working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a hack to re-enable `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec` in Jasmine 2 (sort of, `result` isn't the full `spec` object, but contains `id`, `description`, `fullName`, `failedExpectations`, and `passedExpectations`):

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specStarted(result) {
        jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec = result;
    },
    specDone() {
        jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice! I never thought to (ab)use Jasmine's reporters to replace this bit of functionality, and it doesn't seem hacky to me at all. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/Lfvhjdjh/1/) an updated fiddle showing this used in place of the old `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec`, and it really does allow you to inspect the results of spec right after it completes.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the best answer, as it's a clean solution that provides the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Brilliant solution. WOW :D @tlrobinson Thanks :)

Comment: Note that if you are using TypeScript in your project, it will claim that `currentSpec` doesn't have the property `failedExpectations`. If you inspect `currentSpec` at runtime, however, you will see that it DOES include that property and the others in this answer. The simplest way to fix this is to just cast to the `any` type. `specStarted(result: any)` in the `addReporter` code, and `const currentSpec: any = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec` from within your spec code.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out how to grab a reference to the results of a failed spec with Jasmine 2.3.4, but I'm not sure it's going to be exactly what you're looking for.

I used the vanilla PlayerSpec.js file that comes installed with the Jasmine setup. I ran the SpecRunner.html file to perform the test.

Here is what I changed in the the PlayerSpec file:

```
describe("Player", function() {
  var player;
  var song;
  var index = 0;

  beforeEach(function() {
    player = new Player();
    song = new Song();
    this.index = index++;
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    if (this.index > 0)
    {   var failed = jsApiReporter.specResults(this.index -1, 1)[0].failedExpectations;
        console.log('failed: ', failed);
        if (failed.length > 0)
        {
            console.log('After: ', this, failed[0].message);
            alert('ha');
        }
    }
  });
  it("should not fail", function()
  { expect(1).toEqual(2);
  });
...
```

The rest of the file is the same as it originally was.

Here is what I changed:

Added an index variable to keep track of the current spec number.

In the beforeEach function, I added the index value to the "this" object that gets passed between the it, beforeEach, and afterEach functions. This allows me to communicate between them all as necessary. I'm only using this mechanism to pass the index. Beware! If you just try to use the index value, it won't work! The functions process asynchronously, so there's a good possibility the index value will NOT be what you expect in the afterEach function.

In the afterEach function, I check to make sure the index is greater than 0. In my local testing, the first spec fails, but that is not recognized until the SECOND time the afterEach is called. This is one of the reasons I'm not sure this will work llke you want. I then grab a reference to the failedExpectations and do some conditional processing if I recognize an error.

The last change that is present is the addition of a new spec that will generate a failure.

Here's a poor copy of my FireBug console results:

```
failed: [Object { matcherName="toEqual",  message="Expected 1 to equal 2.",  stack="stack@http://localhost:4...ne-2.3.4/boot.js:110:5\n",  more...}]
PlayerSpec.js (line 15)
After: Object { index=1} Expected 1 to equal 2.
PlayerSpec.js (line 18)
failed: []
PlayerSpec.js (line 15)
failed: []
PlayerSpec.js (line 15)
failed: []
PlayerSpec.js (line 15)
failed: []
PlayerSpec.js (line 15)
```

This problem has been a journey for me. Sadly, I must move on to other things.

I sincerely hope this either solves your problem or at least points you in the right direction. Hopefully, it will help others, too.

Good Luck!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for all the effort you've put into this. I'll need a little while to digest this and really understand what's going on and if it solves my problem. At the very least, this is the closest thing I've seen anyone come up with for being able to access the Jasmine internals the way we were able to in version 1.3.

Comment: Wow... I took a long time to come back to this, sorry about that. I'm impressed at the out-of-the-box solution you've come up with. I'd of course much rather not have to modify Jasmine directly, but I'm accepting this as the best (and assumedly only) solution. However, the need for this was just debugging information anyway, so I think I'll stick to vanilla Jasmine for now. Thank you so much for all the effort you put into this one.

Comment: I'm trying something similar now, but it seems that `jsApiReporter` doesn't get the results immediately so only about a half of the specs during their `afterEach` can get the spec resut. This is with 2.4.1.

Comment: maybe `jsApiReporter.specs()` will be more helpfule

Answer (score 1):

I'm still using Jasmine 1.2 so perhaps things are different in Jasmine 2.0.

In your afterEach function, you should be able to access the current spec that just completed by using:

```
var currentSpec = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec;
```

That will return an object that has many properties. One of them is how many of the embedded tests passed (results_.passedCount).

You could test against that value and perform your logging appropriately.

Good luck!

Comment: In searching for an answer I'd run across code similar to what you've posted, but starting with Jasmine 2.0 they've removed the `currentSpec` property so that I can no longer get at it this way.

Comment: I just downloaded version 2.3.4 and ran the command listed in my response. There is still a currentSpec property on the jasmine.getEnv() object. If it was removed in version 2.2, it's now back in version 2.3.4. You can verify the existence or absence by using a simple console.log message in the afterEach function. When I ran it on my local machine, it showed the currentSpec.

Comment: I just upgraded to 2.3.4 as well, hoping. But when I run `console.log(jasmine.version + ' ' + jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec)` inside my `afterEach()`, I get `2.3.4 undefined`. I'm curious how you're able to see it...

Comment: Try using console.log(jasmine.version, jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec); currentSpec is an object. It should be viewable in FireBug or the developer console of Chrome/IE. I never concatenate values in console.log, I just separate them with commas. ::shrug::

Comment: I see the behavior you're talking about now. I started with a plain vanilla setup and tried it with the Player spec. My project test environment is highly customized. I run tests for all my libraries from a single page. Let me take a look at that closer to see if somewhere I'm modifying the jasmine behavior. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help. I've updated the question to include a fiddle and mention the Jasmine 1.3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar on jasmine 2.5.2 (having custom logger object which would print out only when test fails, without having to do it manually).

Struggled quite a bit to make it work generically through beforeEach/afterEach, finally I caved in to an uglier solution

```
// logger print on fail

function collectSpecs(suite: jasmine.Suite): jasmine.Spec[] {
    const result: jasmine.Spec[] = [];
    const process = [suite];
    while (process.length) {
        const suite = process.pop();
        const children = <jasmine.SuiteOrSpec[]> <any> suite.children; // wrong jasmine typing
        children.forEach(item => {
            switch (item.constructor.name) {
                case "Suite":
                    process.push(<jasmine.Suite>item);
                    break;
                case "Spec":
                    result.push(<jasmine.Spec>item);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
}

function findSpec(specId: string): jasmine.Spec {
    const rootSuite: jasmine.Suite = jasmine.getEnv()["topSuite"]();
    return collectSpecs(rootSuite)
        .filter(s => `${s.id}` === specId)[0];  // wrong jasmine typing on id
}

const loggerSpecProperty = "logger";

function createReporter(): jasmine.CustomReporter {
    return {
        specDone: (result: jasmine.CustomReporterResult) => {
            const spec = findSpec(result.id);
            if (result.failedExpectations.length) {
                const logger: modLog.MemoryLogger = spec[loggerSpecProperty];
                if (logger) {
                    console.log(`\nfailed spec logger:\n${logger.lines.join("\n")}`);
                }
            }
            delete spec[loggerSpecProperty];
        }
    };
}

export function registerReporter(): void {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(createReporter());
}

function createLogger(): modLog.MemoryLogger {
    return new modLog.MemoryLogger(modLog.LogLevel.debug);
}

interface IItCallback {
    (done?: Function): void;
}

interface IItFunctionTyping {
    (name: string, callback: IItCallback): void;
}

interface IItFunction {
    (name: string, callback: IItCallback): jasmine.Spec;
}

// bad typings on it/xit/fit, actually returns Spec but is typed as void
export function lit(fnIt: IItFunctionTyping, name: string, callback: IItCallback): jasmine.Spec {
    function inner(spec: jasmine.Spec, done?: Function) {
        const log = createLogger();
        this.log = log;
        spec[loggerSpecProperty] = log;
        callback.call(this, done);
    }
    const itFunc = <IItFunction> (fnIt || it);
    if (callback.length) {
        const spec = itFunc(name, function (done) {
            inner.call(this, spec, done);
        });
        return spec;
    } else {
        const spec = itFunc(name, function () {
            inner.call(this, spec);
        });
        return spec;
    }
}
```

some unneccessary type mumbo jumbo there due to @types/jasmine obscuring some details of the actual implementation (I suppose it's on purpose, typing version matches the jasmine package version), but I also wanted to practice my TypeScript

passing "it" function to still allow for xit/fit when needed
modLog is my logger module, override this to suite your needs

usage:

instead of

```
it("should do something", function (done) {
    done();
});
```

use

```
lit(it, "should do something", function (done) {
    this.log.debug("test");
    fail("test output");
    done();
});
```

(not very well documented but I think you can get the picture)

it would be much nicer if there was a way for customReporter to access the spec context

(then again this all is basically only for debugging purposes, you could as well add console.log to specific test when it fails and you're struggling with the details, but it was interesting excercise in getting to know jasmine a bit more)