# how to get the result of a test in the afterEach in Jasmine

Tags: logging, jasmine, protractor

I am writing a global afterEach to console.log some logging only when the test failed.

```
jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().afterEach({
            fn: function () {

                if(\*test failed */){
                    console.log('print some logs');
                }
            }
     });
```

I searched a little bit and i found this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39882823/4324176

but this one is not correct as per Jasmine documentation here 
https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

> specDone is invoked when an it and its associated beforeEach and
>   afterEach functions have been run.

so basically my code in the protractor.conf.js onPrepare() is

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
        specStarted(result) {
            jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec = result;
        },
        specDone() {
            jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec = null;
        }
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().afterEach({
            fn: function () {
             const currentSpec = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec;

                if(currentSpec.failedExpectations.length){
                    console.log('print some logs');
                }
            }
     });
```

but the problem is currentSpec.failedExpectations is always [] because the result is not yet updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i just found out that my solution is working, currentSpec.failedExpectations returns [] when the tests pass but when the test fail i actually get a big json response with the  failure message and everything.

I will keep the question/answer here may be it will be helpful for others.